# qTranslate get content by language

Tags: multi-language, plugin-qtranslate

How do you get the content by id and by specific language?

I need to display two specific language content in a page, regardless of the session's language. 
So far, this is my progress: this works fine for getting the content by id of the active language:

```
<?php $id=47; $post = get_page($id); $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); echo $content;  ?>
```

How to apply a specific language to the filter?

Thanks for the help. Sziro

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You must use the qTranslate native functions to do your job. Use `qtrans_use`, that is the function that do all the job in qTranslate. It's defined in qtranslate_core.php, line 747

```
function qtrans_use($lang, $text, $show_available=false)
```

Use it on the raw content of the post!

Try this code:

```
<?php 
 $id=47; $post = get_page($id); 
 $content = qtrans_use('en', $post->post_content,false); 
 echo $content;  
?>
```

In this example, it will return the *English* version of your text! Substitute it with the desired language identifier to translate into another language!

Comment: Yes, glad to have helped you!

Comment: This works perfectly, but it took me a few attempts to realise that the `get_page($id)` bit is important. By the time you're rendering the view, qTranslate has already modified the contents of `$post` to only contain the current language, so you need to load it again to get the options for all languages.

Comment: @keatch can you help me with this plugin it keep on showing english text always, I have installed it properly, do i need to make any other changes in code? or it will work normally without doing anything

Comment: If you still need help you can contact me personally or ask here. I'd be glad to help out. @Jack

Comment: side question, how to get the current language identifier?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor to get the current language identifier you can use many ways but most recommended is: `qtrans_getLanguage()`.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function qtrans_use() in idex.php file when i used above code

Comment: For @vrajesh and other qtranslate-x users, use `qtranxf_use` . Function is defined in qtranslate-core.php as `function qtranxf_use($lang, $text, $show_available=false, $show_empty=false)`