# qTranslate get content by language using wp_query

Tags: wp-query, multi-language, plugin-qtranslate

I've similar problem to the issue described [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51946/qtranslate-get-content-by-language/125365?noredirect=1#comment176740_125365).

On my bilingual website here http://redscouseworld.com/ I'd like to display posts only in Polish language.

And here http://redscouseworld.com/en/ I want to show posts written in English only.

I added following code to my homepage:

```
<ul>
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=10' ); ?>
<?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<li><?php the_excerpt(__('(more…)')); ?></li>
<?php endwhile;?>
</ul>
```

And you can see that on English version both post types are being displayed (Polish and English) - half of them as untranslated ones. How can I display only proper ones on each site?

I tried to hide them using qTranslate function "Hide untranslated content" but the result was empty page.

I'd be grateful for your help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try this solution http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51946/qtranslate-get-content-by-language/125365?noredirect=1#comment176740_125365

Comment: Yes I tired to paste this code:
`<?php 
 $id=47; $post = get_page($id); 
 $content = qtrans_use('en', $post->post_content,false); 
 echo $content;  
?>` 
but nothing happened